# Sort a for loop that contains data from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

I writing a python code that I want to sort emloyees by their height and if heights were same, sort them by their weights
because I'm calling employees name and they charactrestics from MySQL database, it's quite hard for me to code it...

code:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='123', host='127.0.0.1', database='company_workers')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM workers;"
cursor.execute(query)

for (name, height, weight) in sorted(cursor, key = lambda height: height > height):
    print("%s %s %s" % (name, height, weight))
```

output:

```
Jack 75 180
Charlie 90 190
Chris 75 175
```

I even used sorted method with lambda func(maybe I wrote it down in wrong way...)
and I'd be pleased if you show me the way how can I sort with their weights after the heights being same...

desired output:

```
Charlie 90 190
Jack 75 180
Chris 75 175
```

Comment: [`.sorted()`'s key function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) isn't a comparison function. Instead it's a function to make the sort key from a single element of the Iterable you are sorting.

Comment: Why sort in python if you can simply get the data sorted to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the data via mysql query itself

```
select * from workers order by height desc, weight desc;
```

this will sort the rows by height first and if two or more rows have same height then it will sort them by weight

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention is sort weight from the smallest number to bigger(I just started mysql Im not used to it)

Comment: here you go https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/ one step at a time

Answer (score 1):

Just change your sql query and return it ordered:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='123', host='127.0.0.1', database='company_workers')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM workers order by height desc, weight desc, name;"
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

And in data you will have the ordered information

Answer (score 0):

Let mysql do it for you:

`SELECT height,weight,<other fields> FROM workers ORDER BY height, weight;`